# How to access an extended interface on an interceptor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-interception

We have a multi-binding defined in a `NinjectModule` for some `IInspection` interface, like this:

```
private void BindCodeInspectionTypes()
{
    var inspections = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                              .GetTypes()
                              .Where(type => type.BaseType == typeof (InspectionBase));

    // multibinding for IEnumerable<IInspection> dependency
    foreach (var inspection in inspections)
    {
        var binding = Bind<IInspection>().To(inspection).InSingletonScope();
        binding.Intercept().With<TimedCallLoggerInterceptor>();
        binding.Intercept().With<EnumerableCounterInterceptor<InspectionResultBase>>();
    }
}
```

So the interceptor proxy types will be for `IInspection`. However some of the `inspection` types implement an `IParseTreeInspection` interface, which *extends* `IInspection`:

```
public interface IParseTreeInspection : IInspection
{
    ParseTreeResults ParseTreeResults { get; set; }
}
```

The problem this creates is with this bit of code that consumes the interceptors - the injected proxy types understandably don't seem to know anything about `IParseTreeInspection`, so this `foreach` loop doesn't iterate even once:

```
var enabledParseTreeInspections = _inspections.Where(inspection => 
    inspection.Severity != CodeInspectionSeverity.DoNotShow 
 && inspection is IParseTreeInspection);

foreach (var parseTreeInspection in enabledParseTreeInspections)
{
    (parseTreeInspection as IParseTreeInspection).ParseTreeResults = parseTreeWalkResults;
}
```

Is there any way I can multi-bind `IInspection` (i.e. constructor-inject `IEnumerable<IInspection>`) *and* still be able to tell `IParseTreeInspection` instances when Ninject is injecting interceptors?

Comment: unrelated just wanted to say congrats on the MVP, was checking out your profile and saw you got it this year... was it a hard interview/application process after the nomination?

Comment: @Kubie thanks! the form took a couple of days to fill up (you need to enumerate all your eligible contributions for the year - I gotta update my stuff for *this* year now), then there was a phone interview, ..then I woke up on Jan 1st with a congratulations email from Microsoft! =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
foreach (var inspection in inspections)
{
    if (typeof (IParseTreeInspection).IsAssignableFrom(inspection))
    {
        var binding = Bind<IParseTreeInspection>()
            .To(inspection)
            .InSingletonScope()
            .Named(inspection.FullName);

        binding.Intercept().With<TimedCallLoggerInterceptor>();
        binding.Intercept().With<EnumerableCounterInterceptor<InspectionResultBase>>();

        Bind<IInspection>().ToMethod(
            c => c.Kernel.Get<IParseTreeInspection>(inspection.FullName));
    }
    else
    {
        var binding = Bind<IInspection>().To(inspection).InSingletonScope();
        binding.Intercept().With<TimedCallLoggerInterceptor>();
        binding.Intercept().With<EnumerableCounterInterceptor<InspectionResultBase>>();
    }
}
```

This code checks if the type is assignable from `IParseTreeInspection`, i.e., it implements `IParseTreeInspection`, and if so, it creates a named binding from `IParseTreeInspection` to this type and configures the interception here. This will make sure that the proxy objects (created by the interceptor) will implement `IParseTreeInspection`. Then it creates another binding from `IInspection` to a delegate invocation that would use the kernel to resolve `IParseTreeInspection` via the the first binding (using the binding name).